# C# WinForms - Instance of Form Not Showing Label Values Set in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a legacy single form app and I wanted to add a few other forms to it.

So I add a form, an aboutBox to start off with, in the designer of the form I set the text property of various labels to what I want and I can see them change on the form design view. I then instantiate and display the form inside the click function of a button on the main form:

AboutBox1 aboutBox = new AboutBox1();
aboutBox.Show();

But then at run time the form appears with default placeholder text in all the labels - it completely ignores what I set in the designer?

Comment: Have you set the label's `Name` property instead of the `Text` property? (The designer sets both properties to something like `Label1` when you insert them. So it is easy to confuse both properties.)

Comment: Go to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file under the `Properties` folder and modify the assembly attributes there.

Comment: Thanks Oliver and Reza, I've got that sorted now. I've filled the details that I wanted out into the AssemplyInfo.cs file - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set your content from code instead of from designer?
About box shows default Application info from app manifest, on runing. Maybe it's a good way to create similar window by "Form" template.

In constructor default window AboutBox you can see this:

```
this.Text = String.Format("Information about {0}", AssemblyTitle);
this.labelProductName.Text = AssemblyProduct;
this.labelVersion.Text = String.Format("Version {0}", AssemblyVersion);
this.labelCopyright.Text = AssemblyCopyright;
this.labelCompanyName.Text = AssemblyCompany;
this.textBoxDescription.Text = AssemblyDescription;
```

This some lines is responsible to override your data after lauch. Change it and try again.

Comment: Ah I feel so dumb now - yes you are absolutely correct. Sorry I should have checked this - thanks for the quick answer.